# How to match the beginning and end of a plain text table (+---+---+) with regex?

Tags: regex

Plain text tables as exported by pandoc look like this:

```
+------+-------+
| x    | y     |
+======+=======+
| 1    | 4     |
| 2    | 5     |
| 3    | 6     |
+------+-------+
```

goal: find such tables and surround them to with "```" in the line before and after the table

````
```
+------+-------+
| x    | y     |
+======+=======+
| 1    | 4     |
| 2    | 5     |
| 3    | 6     |
+------+-------+
```
````

(I escaped the "`" otherwise it marks code block boundaries and ends the just started code block)

I can find the horizontal cell dividers with regex `^\+.*\+$`.

...but I suppose I need to find the top and bottom one with a look-aheads and look-behinds to check no further of +| which mark borders of the table exist in the next or previous line. But, I can't figure out how. Someone got some ideas?

Comment: Hehe, a quick formatting tip: Indent the code you want to show as code (4 spaces). Then you can show back-ticks too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching:

```
\+-+\+-+\+[\s\S]+?\+-+\+-+\+
```

then replace with:

```
`$&`
```

**Explanation** - all those plus signs :-)

`\+` - match a literal `+`

`-+` - match a hyphen `-` one or more times

`\+` - match a literal `+`

`-+` - match a hyphen `-` one or more times

`\+` - match a literal `+`

`[\s\S]+?` match any character one or more times (NON greedy = as few as possible) - this includes newlines

`\+` - match a literal `+`

`-+` - match a hyphen `-` one or more times

`\+` - match a literal `+`

`-+` - match a hyphen `-` one or more times

`\+` - match a literal `+`

Now replace with the whole match surrounded with back-ticks

Set the `global` flag to replace all.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what programming language you are working with.
The fillowing example works in Python.
Regex Pattern, using flag `s` include newline in `.` .
As the header line begins with the beginning of a line `^` and the footer line ends with a line end `$` we shouldn't have any problems.
I have forbidden the string `-+-` to avoid capturing 2 tables at a time, with everything in between, if we have 2 tables on the same page.

```
"^(\+(-+\+)+((?!(-+-)).)*\+(-+\+)+)$"gms
```

Substituting with

````
```\n\1\n```
````

See
https://regex101.com/r/PslCIX/2